# App WebView + Impressão

Tags: javascript, app

Criei um APP que abre um site onde faço login, então preencho uma planilha no final pelo Google Chrome ele gera um comando de impressão (posso escolher em salvar ou imprimir).

No meu app faço tudo quando finalizo o formulário pede para abrir o Google Chrome e tenho que fazer tudo de novo pelo navegador, alguém tem uma solução para gerar um comando de print ou gerar PDF ?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wv;
    String mypage = "http://www.refimat.com.br/5Tabelas.html";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv.loadUrl(mypage);
    }
}
```

Codigo .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo, poderia discorrer um pouco mais do seu problema, acredito que tenha ficado um pouco confuso a segunda parte.

Comment: Boa noite amigo, tenho um site e criei um App de forma simples só com um WebVIew entrando diretamente no site, então faço o login nele e preencho um cadastro como teste e o App não gera à impressão como o Google Chrome normal faz, ele abre novamente o site por um navegador na parte de login.
Então eu gostaria de uma ajuda para fazer um comando de impressão direto no App.